# Represent unicode utf-8 or print the list that elements as input from keyboard?

Tags: python, character-encoding

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def present_unicode(list):
    for a in list:
        print u"%s" % a
```

TRY:

```
list1 = ['១','៤','០']#this list is what I input with the khmer keyboard.
print list1 
>>> ['\xe1\x9f\xa1', '\xe1\x9f\xa4', '\xe1\x9f\xa0']

list2 =  [u'\u17E2', u'\u17E4', u'\u17E0'] # <=>['\xe1\x9f\xa1', '\xe1\x9f\xa4', '\xe1\x9f\xa0']
print list2
>>>['\\u17E2', '\\u17E4', '\\u17E0']
```

OUTPUT:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    present_unicode(list1) #output the same element as my input keyboard
    present_unicode(list2)#output '\\u17E2', '\\u17E4', '\\u17E0' ???
```

My question is: 
With `list2` how can I display as what I input from keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unicode` literals.

["Unicode in Python, Completely Demystified"](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Comment: @stackunderflow, to be as clear as possible, in this situation, this basically means adding a `u` prefix to your string literals, i.e. `list2 = [u'\u17E2', u'\u17E4', u'\u17E0']`. The list will still display escaped characters like `u'\u17e0'` but if you print the strings directly, they ought to display correctly. (@Ignacio, +1 by the way.)